# Angular Material - Change color of mat-list-option on selected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template, angular-material2, angular2-material

How can I change the color of selected option of `mat-list-option`?
Right now I have something like this:

**Current list**
[image]

I want to change the color of whole option or card 'on select' to green. Something like this: [image]

My code is like this:

```
<mat-selection-list #list>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let yuvak of yuvaks">
    {yuvak.name}
    {yuvak.phonenumber}
     </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use **`aria-selected="true"`** attribute from **`mat-list-option`** tag to target the selected option,
 and provide corresponding css properties for the same.

```
mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.7);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)**

Comment: I haven't implemented but from the demo i think this will work. However, Where can i find the documentation for the attribute likes aria-selected?.

Comment: please search the net, because i looked for the dom changes whenever i checked the mat-list-option and found that this attribute was triggered, so i went ahead with the attribute to style mat-list-option tag.

Comment: @TanmayParmar please upvote the answer as well, its helpful for users looking for answers.

Comment: Great solution. I've been using a method in typescript that takes an item an checks if it's in the list of selected items, but targeting the actual attributes angular already provided is much better. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

**Drop Down:**

The `mat-list-option` has `mat-option.mat-active` which triggered when option is active and `mat-option.mat-selected` when an option is selected. Add the following to your CSS to modify the active or selected styles, depends on your need.

```
.mat-option.mat-active {
  background: blue !important;
}

.mat-option.mat-selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fknzxe)

**Selection List:**

The selection list has `aria-selected` attribute and by default it is `false`. It changes to `true` if you select the item. All you need is to set CSS as below:

```
.mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: rgba(200, 210, 90, 0.7);
}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrrcei)

Comment: i am using selection list. this is dropdown.

Comment: @TanmayParmar Edit my answer for selection list.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works fine, but it uses a **hardcoded color value** (`background: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.7)`).
 This approach will actually break your styles and colors if you decide to switch to another pre-build material theme or use a custom theme (as described in [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) page).

So, if you use SCSS, you can use the following code in your component's style file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: mat-color($mat-light-theme-background, hover, 0.12);
}
```

The above code is adapted from **`mat-select options`** - in this way, you will have a consistent look in the entire app: 
`.mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-multiple) { background: mat-color($background, hover, 0.12);}`

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change-qaq1xr

Or, if you use a dark theme, change code as follows:

```
mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: mat-color($mat-dark-theme-background, hover, 0.12);
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change-w8beng

If you just want to use a custom color, I suggest to pick one from [Material Specs](https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors), that are also exposed in Angular Material Design [scss](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss).

```
$primaryPalette: mat-palette($mat-green);

mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: mat-color($primaryPalette, 500);
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change-tt3nyj

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using `[aria-selected]` seems too 'obtuse'.

You can also grab the selected state of a node and use that as required.

##### Example 1: You have a child component you need to pass the state to

```
<mat-list-option #option>

   <app-custom-list-option-widget [selected]="option.selected"></app-custom-list-option-widget>

</mat-list-option>
```

##### Example 2: You want to set a custom css class instead of using `[aria-selected]`

```
.is-selected { color: red; }
```

Then in the template:

```
<mat-list-option #option>

   <span [class.is-selected]="option.selected"> Option text </span>

</mat-list-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

For mat-list-option properties css changes,

to change onHover css :

```
   .mat-list-option:hover {
      width: 270px!important;
    }
```

to change OnActive css:

```
 .mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
      width: 270px!important;
    }
    .mat-list-option:active,
    .mat-list-text:active{
    background-color: none!important;
    }
```